# Displaying HTML emails in PHP using IMAP

Tags: php, html, imap

I'm using the imap PHP functions "fetchstructure" or "imap_body" depending on message type to get the message body from a POP3 account. I first store emails in my database (including HTML) and then my PHP displays emails and their content.

My problem is the following: once I have the emails HTML content, is there any good practice or a common way/function of displaying the HTML emails whithout messing up the rest of my HTML page ?

Should i display emails in plain text format ? And how do other web mail clients do to display HTML stuff... do they parse it ?

PS: i'd rather not use an iframe..

Thanks you for your time,
Romain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure i answer my own question here, but do other clients use HTML purifiers ? I've found this one, which helps, but that does not give my an answer on how other clients do.

http://htmlpurifier.org/

Seems a great class anyway so i hope it helps.